# Perl 5 OOP programming

Tags: python, perl

I'm trying to port the following python program to perl5:

```
import numpy as np


class Hensuu:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


class Kansuu:
    def __call__(self, input):
        x = input.data
        y = x ** 2
        output = Hensuu(y)
        return output

x = Hensuu(np.array(9.0))
f = Kansuu()
y = f(x)

print(type(y))
print(y.data)
```

---

### <class '**main**.Hensuu'>
81.0

Hensuu.pm

```
package Hensuu;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
our $version = 1.0.0;
sub new {
    our ($class,$data) = @_;
    my $self = {data=>$data};
    bless $self,$class;
    return $self;
}
1;
```

---

step1.pl

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Hensuu;
use PDL;
use PDL::Matrix;
my $datas = mpdl [[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]];
my $x = Hensuu->new($datas);
print($x=>$datas);
```

---

Kansuu.pm

```
package Kansuu;
#use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Hensuu;
sub call {
    my ($self,$input) = @_;
    my $x = {$input => $data};
    #print($x);
    my $y = $x ** 2;
    my $output = Hensuu->new($y);
    return($output);
}
1;
```

---

step2.pl

```
#!perl
#use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use PDL;
use PDL::Matrix;
use Hensuu;
use Kansuu;

my $a = mpdl [9.0];
my $x = Hensuu->new($a);
#my $f = Kansuu;
#my $y = $f->call($x);
my $y = Kansuu->call($x);
print($x=>$a);
print(ref($y));
print($y);
```

---

emit(step2.pl)

```
Hensuu=HASH(0x1faf80)
[
 [9]
]
HensuuHensuu=HASH(0x25b71c0)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

The above program (step2.pl),
I want to set the display to "81" with print($y) ;, but I can't.
Environment is Windows 10 pro, strawberry perl PDL edition (5.32.1.1),
The IDE is intellij idea community edition perl plugin (2020.3).

Comment: If you want to use modern OOP in perl look into Moose or Moo

Answer (score 5):

Hensuu.pm:

```perl
package Hensuu;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, $data) = @_;
    return bless {data => $data}, $class
}

sub data {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{data}
}

1
```

Kansuu.pm:

```perl
package Kansuu;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Hensuu;

sub call {
    my ($input) = @_;
    my $x = $input->data;
    my $y = $x ** 2;
    my $output = Hensuu->new($y);
    return $output->data
}

1
```

step2.pl:

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

use PDL;
use PDL::Matrix;
use Hensuu;
use Kansuu;

my $p = mpdl [9.0];
my $x = Hensuu->new($p);
my $y = Kansuu::call($x);
say $y;
```

- Don't use `our` variables for things that don't need to be global.
- Don't use `$a` as a lexical variable, it's a special variable used in [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort).
- Low level Perl OO doesn't create accessors  for attributes, you need to implement them yourself (see [Moo](http://p3rl.org/Moo) or [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose) for higher level ways).
- Kansuu is not an OO class, use a fully qualified subroutine instead of a method.

Comment: Re "*Kansuu is not an OO class, use a fully qualified subroutine instead of a method*", There's no problem with static classes. `sub call { my ($self,$input) = @_; ... }` and `Kansuu->call($x)`  was fine. (But so is your alternative.)

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, but if there's no instance and no class attribute, I tend not to include OO at all (kind of Occam's razor). Also, I'd use `$class` instead of `$self` for a class method.

Comment: Re "*Occam's razor*", Kansuu::call is not simpler than Kansuu->call (and that's not what Occam's razor means).

Comment: Re "*I'd use $class instead of $self for a class method.*", ditto.